# TFS Branches to be made Identical

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I had created TWO Branches VER 4.1 and Ver 4.2 From Ver 4.0 in VSTS 2010. But we used only Ver 4.1 till date. Now we would like to have all check-in and data from 4.1 to 4.2 as it will be used for future development activities. Please help me how to merge the data from 4.1 into 4.2 branch 
Note - 4.1 and 4.2 were created from 4.0(4.1 is latest branch now and has recent check-Ins)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the possible way i can think about it

1. Create a label on 4.0 (so that in future you can create branch from this label)
2. Now merge VER 4.1 with 4.0.
3. and then refresh/merge  VER4.2 with 4.0